# Thymeleaf: retrieve value of hidden input to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to get values stored in the hidden inputs by creating submit button. But the program won't bind values to the object.

**HTML file**

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/client/1/allprocedures}" th:object="${treatment}">
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${treatment.ClientID}" name="1" id="1">
         <input type="hidden" th:value="${treatment.ProcedureID}" name="128" id="128">
         <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mt-2 w-100" type="submit" value="Buy"/>
</form>
```

**Controllers**

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/allprocedures/add")
    public String addProcedure(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("treatment", new Treatment());
        return "addProcedure";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{id}/allprocedures")
    public String saveProcedure(@ModelAttribute("treatment") Treatment treatment,
                               @PathVariable("id") int id,
                               BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "procedurelist";
        return "redirect:/client/"+ id +"/allprocedures";
    }
```

**Treatment model**

```
public class Treatment {
    private int ClientID, ProcedureID;
}
// constructor, getters and setters
```

Controller works fine. When i input data manually by using text input, the program works as should:

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/client/1/allprocedures}" th:object="${treatment}">
         <input type="text" th:field="${treatment.ClientID}">
         <input type="text" th:field="${treatment.ProcedureID}">
         <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mt-2 w-100" type="submit" value="Buy"/>
</form>
```

At the same time, when i use `th:field` and `name="" id=""`, it won't work too.
I also tried using `th:value="name=""`, but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="${treatment.ClientID}" th:attr="name=1">
<input type="hidden" th:field="${treatment.ProcedureID}" th:attr="name=128">
```

Can somebody help or advise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Small side note: You don't have to use `th:method="POST"`, since this is a literal value (`POST`) and not a Thymeleaf expression. You can just use `method="POST"`. Having said that, I assume using `th:method="POST"` will still work as expected, in this specific case, because `POST` is a Thymeleaf [literal token](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#literal-tokens), here.

Comment: Use `th:field` ditch `th:value`, `name` and `id` those actually break proper binding when used with `th:field`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{ClientID}">
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{ProcedureID}">
```

Notice the use of * instead of $. Also, values in the `th:field` attributes are properties of the object specified by the `th:object` attribute. `th:field` will render the id and name attributes for you.

Comment: I tried this one too and put my data into `name=""`, but it still won't work. I assume the program retrieves ClientID and ProcedureID with zero values. I can't figure out how to render my values. Could you advise? And thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't use `name="..."`.  This can break the binding. The `th:field` will add both id and name attributes. Also, you are initializing treatment with `new Treatment()`. Both ClientID and ProcedureID will have the values defined in this constructor. If you don't explicitly initialize them they will have value 0. If you need to have them initialized to something else do so in `addProcedure()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" hidden th:field="*{ClientID}" th:value="${treatment.ClientID}">
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).